# How to automatically convert derived class object to new base class object?

Tags: c#, parent-child

`B` is a class derived from `A`. I need to create a new object `A` from existing object `B`.

I need this because in my application I use a lot of `A` instances which are much more light weigh than `B` (which holds a lot of reference data), otherwise I would run out of memory.

How do I convert `B` to `A` without manually copying all `A`'s fields' values in a custom method?

Comment: Memory shouldn't be a concern, unless you're talking millions of `B`s, or loading multi-MB images into memory.  What makes you think it would be an issue?

Comment: There are around 80 millions of instances, so memory is of concern.

Comment: You need to keep 80 million instances in memory at the same time?  Wow.

Comment: If B already exists in memory once as you say in your second statement, passing it around or referencing it through other variables should not have any memory impact

Comment: @Bobson It's a game server. I'd like to keep latency low.

Comment: @swiftgp each `A` has its own float value which is a critical part of the plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using composition (i.e. your `B` contains a private `A` as member data) instead of inheritance. Add a method to `B` to return its `A`, so you can keep hold of it while the rest of the `B` is garbage collected.

Comment: Or, vice-versa.  An `A` contains a `B`, and that gets set to `null` when no longer needed.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with this way.

Comment: @Bobson Indeed. Or a dictionary with `A` as the key and `B` as the value. The important thing is to break the *is-a* relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it:

```
var a = (A)b;
```

or

```
var a = b as A;
```

A class that extends another can always be cast down to the more primitive version. Note that under the hood this is still the same instance of `B`, you are just treating it as `A`. If you are looking to create a clone of B, then you should add a method to B:

```
public class B : A  
{
    public A Clone()
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.SomeProperty = this.SomeProperty;
        ...etc...
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't cast for some reason. Some say it's the principles of OOP, but I say if it doesn't do what I tell it to do, it's not right.

Comment: To your update: my copying method includes getting a memberwise copy of a `B` and casting it to `A`. The casting part doesn't work.

Comment: @user1306322 - Casting doesn't change the type.  It only changes what it's treated as.  Slugster's version creates a brand new A, not a B treated as an A (like yours).